# TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing web application in **AngularJS**. I have below form.

```
<form name="form2" novalidate><multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true"
ng-model="selectedCar" options="c.name for c in cars" change="selected()"></multiselect> 
<input type="file" file-modelsr = "myFileDL" />
<input type="file" file-modelsr="myFileID" />
<input type="submit" value="{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}" class="blue-button" ng-click="saveDetail()">
```

Below is my JS code.

```
var myapp = angular.module('RoslpApp');
(function () {
    angular.module('RoslpApp').controller('CarOutside', ['$scope', '$http', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', '$state', '$stateParams', 'cfg', 'toastr', '$cookieStore', '$filter', '$anchorScroll', '$location', 'fileUpload',
        function ($scope, $http, $translatePartialLoader, $translate, $state, $stateParams, cfg, toastr, $cookieStore, $filter, $anchorScroll, $location, fileUpload) {
            $translatePartialLoader.addPart('ServiceRequest');
            $translate.refresh();
            var cookiePreferredLanguage = $cookieStore.get('PreferredLanguage');
            var LoginID = $cookieStore.get("LoginID");
            var baseurl = cfg.Baseurl;
            $translate.use((cookiePreferredLanguage != null && cookiePreferredLanguage != undefined && cookiePreferredLanguage != "") ? cookiePreferredLanguage : 'de_AR');
            $scope.name = 'World';
            //Bind data to multi select dropdown(location)
            $scope.cars = [{ id: 1, name: 'Audi' }, { id: 2, name: 'BMW' }, { id: 1, name: 'Honda' }];
            $scope.selectedCar = [];
            //Bind data to period
            $scope.periodList = [{ id: 1, period: 'Audi' }, { id: 2, period: 'BMW' }, { id: 1, period: 'Honda' }];

            if ($scope.form2.$valid) {
                $scope.saveDetail = function () {
                    var fileDL = $scope.myFileDL;
                    var fileID = $scope.myFileID;
                    var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
                    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
                };
            } else {
                alert("not valid");
            }
    }]);
})();
```

I am getting below error Cannot read property `$valid` of `undefined` and not able to figure it why I am getting this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please add more JS code

Comment: Added. Thank you. Also i have two directives also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your check to inside of `saveDetail()`. The if `($scope.form2.$valid)` is running when your controller runs, which is before $scope.form2 has any data, and therefore is undefined.

```
       $scope.saveDetail = function() {
            if ($scope.form2.$valid) {
            var fileDL = $scope.myFileDL;
            var fileID = $scope.myFileID;
            var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
            fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            } else {
                alert("not valid");
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having `if.. else` outside the function `saveDetail`, you should maybe put them inside.

Currently, when it tries to execute `$scope.form2.$valid`, the form (`form2`) is not yet initialized and is `undefined`. Which is why you get `$valid` of `undefined`

```
$scope.saveDetail = function () {
  if ($scope.form2.$valid) {
    var fileDL = $scope.myFileDL;
    var fileID = $scope.myFileID;
    var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
  } else {
    alert("not valid");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose `if....else..` inside the `saveDetail()` method.

Moreover, you could pass the `form2.$valid` as a parameter to the method in `ng-submit` as `ng-submit="saveDetail(form2.$valid)"` and check for its truthfulness inside the method body.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.saveDetail = function(valid) {
    if (valid) {
      console.log("valid");
    } else {
      console.log("Not Valid")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="form2" novalidate ng-submit="saveDetail(form2.$valid)">
    <multiselect class="input-xlarge" multiple="true" ng-model="selectedCar" options="c.name for c in cars" change="selected()"></multiselect>
    <input type="file" file-modelsr="myFileDL" />
    <input type="file" file-modelsr="myFileID" />
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'NEXT'}}" class="blue-button">
  </form>
</body>
```